# ASP.Net MVC3, Convert existing MVC project into an AREA

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a few separate ASP.Net MVC3 applications. 
Currently we want all these separate MVC projects to be made as AREAS under a new MVC project. 
It's like creating a central portal from where all these applications will be launched.

I need to know if there is a standard process in making these MVC projects as areas.

And what are the things that I need to worry about.

Thanks in advance.